# Insert multiple data from input Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm making a quiz system. I have 3 tables:

`tests` table

```
id,
title,
total_question,
time,
status,
id_subject
```

`questions` table:

```
id,
content,
optA,
optB,
optC,
optD,
answer,
unit,
id_subject
```

`questions_of_test` table:

```
id,
id_test,
id_question
```

When I create a `test`, after I select `subject`, base on the number of `unit` of that subject will show a number of textbox to fill a number of `question` for each unit.

Example, the subject I selected have 3 unit. It will show 3 textboxes and I fill:

Textbox1: 1
Textbox2: 2
Textbox3: 1

`Total` is 10 question.

**How can I insert this 10 question to `questions_of_test` table.**

This is my some code to show texbox from dropdownlist:

```
$('select').select();
    function get_units() {
        var id = $('#id_subject').val();
        var list = $('#list_unit');
        list.empty();
        var url = "{{ route('test.getunit', ':id') }}";
        url = url.replace(':id', id);
        var success = function (result) {
            if (result.length <= 0) {
                var item = '<div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-12"><input type="text" disabled value="This subject have no question" class="form-control" style="color: #26c6da;"></div></div>';
                list.append(item);
            } else {
                for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    var item = '<div class="form-group"><label for="unit-' + result[i].unit+ '" class="col-sm-12 control-label" style="font-size: medium;">Enter number of question of unit ' + result[i].unit+ ' (have' + result[i].Total + ' questions) <span class="failed">(*)</span></label><div class="col-sm-12"><br><input type="number" min="0" max="' + result[i].Total + '" class="unit_input form-control" onchange="set_sum(' + result[i].Total + ')"  name="unit-' + result[i].unit+ '" id="unit[' + result[i].unit+ '][]" required></div></div>';
                    list.append(item);
                }
            }
        };
        $.get(url, success);
    }
```

I got an array like this:
[image]

I want to Insert random(1) where id_subject = select_id and unit = 1, random(2) where id_subject = select_id and unit = 2... **How can I get it?**

```
<input type="number" name="unit['+result[i].chuong+'][]"></input>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you provide more details?

Comment: please review my update

Comment: So for each unit, You want to take x random questions to the test?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: I have no idea about that, can u help me?

Comment: I can not do much with the infomation you provided but i think you need a post request with data is an array, each element contains unit and quantity of questions.

Comment: I got an array, please review my update

Comment: It depend on your server code but you didn't include it in the question. Look like you are also Vietnamese so you can contact me on linkedin(https://www.linkedin.com/in/cuong-le-b36106180/) for better communication.

Comment: I have sent you a connect

Comment: I haven't received any.

Comment: It say pending, I don't know why? Can u send me a connect, please?[link](http://linkedin.com/in/hoa-huynh-ba4163212)

Comment: Your profile is unavailable.

Comment: can u check again, please?[link](http://linkedin.com/in/hoa-huynh-ba4163212)

Comment: Still unavailable. Do you have fb? My fb: https://www.facebook.com/cuong.ln.97/

Comment: yup, I have sent u a friend request